# Braintree Webhook - Check URL not working

Tags: c#, model-view-controller, webhooks, braintree

I have set up a webhook in my Braintree account https://example.com/Webhook/Accept

I have the site setup to create a Customer & Subscription via a purchase link.

When I make a purchase via the link these are both created ok in the Braintree vault, the webhook fires and I receive 2 notifications.

This all seems great, all is working, except the for 'Check URL' in the Braintree Control panel Webhook section, where im getting a HTTP error 500 internal server error.

I think its a bt_challenge issue on the GET but having tried a few variations I simply cant get it working.

Here is my controller:

```
public class WebhookController : Controller
{
    public IBraintreeConfiguration config = new BraintreeConfiguration();

public ActionResult Accept()
{
    CrmDB db = new CrmDB();
    Log log;

    var gateway = config.GetGateway();

    if (Request.HttpMethod == "POST")
    {
        WebhookNotification webhookNotification = gateway.WebhookNotification.Parse(
            Request.Params["bt_signature"],
            Request.Params["bt_payload"]
            );

        string message = string.Format(
            "[Webhook Received {0}] | Kind: {1} | Subscription: {2}",
            webhookNotification.Timestamp.Value,
            webhookNotification.Kind,
            webhookNotification.Subscription.Id
            );

        System.Console.WriteLine(message);

        // Save to Db
        log = new Log
        {
            Stamp = DateTime.Now,
            App = "api/Webhook/Accept",
            IsInsight = true,
            Insight = message
        };

        // Db
        db.Log.Add(log);
        db.SaveChanges();

        return new HttpStatusCodeResult(200);
    }
    else
    {
        string msg = gateway.WebhookNotification.Verify(Request.QueryString["bt_challenge"]);

        // Save to Db
        log = new Log
        {
            Stamp = DateTime.Now,
            App = "Webhook - bt_challenge",
            IsInsight = true,
            Insight = msg
        };

        // Db
        db.Log.Add(log);
        db.SaveChanges();
        return Content(msg);
    }
}
}
```

I believe the issue is in the else section (ie HTTP GET) but I cant work out what it is.

Why am I getting the 500 internal error from Webhook control Panel?

Comment: Can you confirm your domain is actually `example.com`? That will fail regardless. If not, I recommend providing logs from your webserver that show your webhook is being hit. Those logs should also contain information about why your server is failing.

Comment: @Raymond Berg yeah I changed the domain to example.com as suggested by stack overflow guidelines. The error in the log is what I posted -> 500 internal server error, there is no other detail im afraid.

Comment: I recommend you contact [Braintree support](https://support.braintreepayments.com) to debug further. There are a lot of moving pieces in getting your web server up and accepting this, and debugging integrations/webhooks isn't easy in Stack Overflow.